# why is remote holographic player on HoloLens2 stuck in "receiving" mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine, streaming, hololens

I developed a Unity (Version:2020.3.16f1) project that is "streamed" to a HL2 via Holographic Remoting Player (v2.7.4.0) when in play-mode (openXR is used).
It all worked fine until yesterday morning when I started the play-mode. Since then the Holographic Player on the HL2 is stuck in "Receiving..." eventhough the scene on the laptop is running. I downgraded the HL2 firmware to august 2021 already - didnt help. Does not work either using Wifi nor USBC for connection.

Did anyone ever have this problem ?

Comment: Could you check that is there any network management software (such as anti-virus software, Firewall, VPN, etc.) is running on your PC or network Gateway? Also, as any known issues will be fixed in the latest version, please update to the latest version of HoloLens OS.

Comment: i deactivated my microsoft defender-firewall. no changes unfortunately. To be honest I am not sure if or when the HL2 was updated automatically and whether this triggered the issue. However, I downgraded the firmware to August 2021. I am not sure whether Microsoft Windows 10 was updating itself and cracking all up. Really unclear what is going on. I would be glad if you had more suggestions or hints.

Comment: Did you re-enter the new IP address on the Unity side after connecting with HL2 via USB cable? Also, If the issue still exists, please clone this sample repository, and build on your PC: [remote_openxr](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-HolographicRemoting-Samples/tree/main/remote_openxr). Since the OpenXR Remote app is implemented by using the same technology as Unity HolographicRemoting, so it can help us to troubleshoot.

Comment: In additional to Hernando's suggestion of checking IP via USB cable, please use the USBNCM ip address to have a try: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal#connecting-over-usb

Comment: update: the unity holographic remoting works when selecting H264 as video codec. How does this come?

Comment: @Hernando: i couldnt build the remote_openxr . do you suggest starting an issue on git for that? I have this error: cppwinrt : error ios_base: :failbit set: iostream stream error: iostream stream error: working_directory\remote_openxr\desktop\SampleRemoteOpenXR.dir\Release\Generated Files\winrt/impl/Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentsProvider.0.h and also \remote_openxr\desktop\packages\Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.2.0.220131.2\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.targets(661,9): error MSB3073:

Comment: @Franklin Chen I did change the IP to the USBC port before

Comment: @Both since its hard to find people that actually know how to work with remoting .. is it possible to have gesture control and/or voice control via HL microphone when using unity holographic remoting? if not is it possible to do it when building the app?

Comment: It looks like your Unity Holographic Remoting is working fine now. For your latest question, all inputs from the HoloLens--gaze, gesture, voice, and spatial mapping--are sent to the PC, where content is rendered in a virtual immersive view. The rendered frames are then sent to the HoloLens.

Comment: Ok. You said the gestures etc. are send to the PC. How do I access them and therefore make use of them?

Comment: The easiest way to leverage the Articulated Hand and Eye Tracking in Unity is through MRTK. You can get start with these documentations: [Hand tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/hand-tracking?view=mrtkunity-2021-05), [Eye tracking in the Mixed Reality Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/eye-tracking/eye-tracking-main?view=mrtkunity-2021-05)

Comment: @Hernando: Yes but how do I use these tools when I dont deploy the app on the hololens - is it possible? I start remote holographing inside unity on the computer as i launch the scene.